# Disappearing documents in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

When opening more than one document in Word 2013, if I hover over the Word icon on the Taskbar, it shows small screen images of my documents.  Sometimes (not always) I open a Word document and it doesn't open the document, but the small screen image shows the title of my document, but there's nothing beneath it.  If I double click on the image, nothing happens, but if I right click and choose restore, Word opens the document in a new window.  What's up with that?

Comment: What other software do you have installed? Did it happen after an update? do you have other software running? This lacks more information.

Comment: Do you open your Word documents inside the file explorer with preview pane turned on ? Disable the preview pane or put all the files on the Desktop and see if the problem occurs again.

Comment: NEEDS A SCREENSHOT

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and running Word 2013 (no update -- I just purchased Office with Word 2013).  I open my Word documents in Word.  This only happens with multiple screens and I just noticed the last time it happened that when I closed the active window, then the "disappearing" document suddenly appears in the active window.  How do I upload a screen shot for you to see?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen too.

What seems to be happening is that Word is opening the document off screen.

If you make sure the document window is selected (not that easy, you need to remember what actions have occurred) then press ctrl-space to get the window menu, then choose move. Now you can use the cursor keys to move the window, a bit of experimenting will show you where it currently is.

It seems to be worse when you have multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fortunately I knew how to avoid it. It is by opening MS Word from start menu and then opening your files one by one from File >> Open.

Comment: When asked whether he opens Word documents from Explorer, the OP replied that he opens them in Word.  What does your answer contribute that the OP doesn't already know?